# SQL average result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have following SQL query

```
SELECT TOP 10000 AVG(DailyNodeAvailability.Availability) AS AVERAGE_of_Availability
FROM Nodes 
INNER JOIN DailyNodeAvailability 
    ON (Nodes.NodeID = DailyNodeAvailability.NodeID)
WHERE 
( DateTime > (GetDate()-7) )
 AND  
(
  (
  (Nodes.Caption LIKE '%server1%') OR 
  (Nodes.Caption LIKE '%server2%') OR 
  (Nodes.Caption LIKE '%server3%') 
  )
)
```

It's giving me average availability report of 3 servers. But I want least availability. For example.

```
Server1 = 100%
Server2 = 97%
Server3 = 88%
```

I want SQL query result in least one which would be Server3 = 88% (Not average)

How do I modify existing query to make it work?

There was confusion so, I am attaching picture of result. Its giving me single result but in average and i don't want average i need least result value in my result, According example.

[image]

Comment: Try using `MIN` instead of `AVG`?  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx

Comment: are you sure you getting 3 results ? it cant be you arenot doing group by ....just avg so you have to get 1 number only ....

Comment: Your current query doesn't produce the data you suggest it should.  It produces a single average without any server identification.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake Query gives me ravage result of all three servers ( single result ) but i gave example if this is the case then i need least one in result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(AVERAGE_of_Availability)
FROM
(
SELECT AVG(DailyNodeAvailability.Availability) AS AVERAGE_of_Availability
FROM Nodes 
INNER JOIN DailyNodeAvailability 
    ON (Nodes.NodeID = DailyNodeAvailability.NodeID)
WHERE 
( DateTime > (GetDate()-7) )
 AND  
(
  (
  (Nodes.Caption LIKE '%server1%') OR 
  (Nodes.Caption LIKE '%server2%') OR 
  (Nodes.Caption LIKE '%server3%') 
  )
)
group by Nodes.Caption
) AvgAvailability
```

This will give you the minimum, but it will not tell for which server it is showing. To get the server name (Nodes.Caption) we have to do a bit more. As it is not in the original query so, I am not including that part, otherwise it will make it a little bit more complicated.

Comment: how does he have 3 results if he didnt write group by ? he should have only 1 scalar value....?

Comment: I was talking about him not you. he cant get 3 results  like he said- only one....

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake Query gives me aravage result of all three servers ( single result ) but i gave example if this is the case then i need least one in result.

Answer (score 2):

Your base query should be written as:

```
SELECT N.Caption AS Server, AVG(A.Availability) AS Avg_Availability
  FROM Nodes AS N
  JOIN DailyNodeAvailability AS A ON (N.NodeID = A.NodeID)
 WHERE DateTime > (GetDate()-7)
   AND (N.Caption LIKE '%server1%' OR
        N.Caption LIKE '%server2%' OR
        N.Caption LIKE '%server3%'
       )
 GROUP BY N.Caption
```

This will give you a list with each server name and the average availability of that server over the last week.

To get the server name with the minimum average availability and its average availability, you have to treat that query as part of a bigger one.  There are two ways to do it in Standard SQL: the long-winded and generally available, and the succinct but less widely available.

The long-winded way ends up writing out that query a couple of times as sub-queries (so, when developing the query, it is crucial to get the first query correct and tested before continuing to the more complex query):

```
SELECT m.server, m.avg_availability
  FROM (SELECT N.Caption AS Server, AVG(A.Availability) AS Avg_Availability
          FROM Nodes AS N
          JOIN DailyNodeAvailability AS A ON (N.NodeID = A.NodeID)
         WHERE DateTime > (GetDate()-7)
           AND (N.Caption LIKE '%server1%' OR
                N.Caption LIKE '%server2%' OR
                N.Caption LIKE '%server3%'
               )
         GROUP BY N.Caption
       ) AS m
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(y.avg_availability) AS min_availability
          FROM (SELECT N.Caption AS Server, AVG(A.Availability) AS Avg_Availability
                  FROM Nodes AS N
                  JOIN DailyNodeAvailability AS A ON (N.NodeID = A.NodeID)
                 WHERE DateTime > (GetDate()-7)
                   AND (N.Caption LIKE '%server1%' OR
                        N.Caption LIKE '%server2%' OR
                        N.Caption LIKE '%server3%'
                       )
                 GROUP BY N.Caption
               ) AS Y
       ) AS x
    ON x.min_availability = m.avg_availability
```

The succinct way to do it uses a common-table expression, aka WITH clause:

```
WITH AvgAvailability AS
    (
    SELECT N.Caption AS Server, AVG(A.Availability) AS Avg_Availability
      FROM Nodes AS N
      JOIN DailyNodeAvailability AS A ON (N.NodeID = A.NodeID)
     WHERE DateTime > (GetDate()-7)
       AND (N.Caption LIKE '%server1%' OR
            N.Caption LIKE '%server2%' OR
            N.Caption LIKE '%server3%'
           )
     GROUP BY N.Caption
    )
SELECT A.Server, A.Avg_Availabilty
  FROM AvgAvailability AS A
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(Avg_Availability) AS Min_Availability
          FROM AvgAvailability
       ) AS M
    ON A.Avg_Availability = M.Min_Availability
```

(Syntax untested.)  I'm not sure whether the succinct option is available in MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this more compactly in SQL Server like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  N.Caption AS Server,
  AVG(A.Availability) AS Avg_Availability
FROM Nodes AS N
JOIN DailyNodeAvailability AS A
ON (N.NodeID = A.NodeID)
WHERE DateTime > (GetDate()-7)
AND N.Caption LIKE '%server[123]%'
GROUP BY N.Caption
ORDER BY AVG(A.Availability)
```